# Front Derailleur Wont Shift

Tags: repair

I'm not too sure what to call this but basically someone whilst riding my bike shifted up too much (basically they mustve pulled on the lever while already being in the big gear) and now as a result both the lever and the button are both jammed and I have no clue what I should do to fix it (being a novice cyclist xD)

[image]

Usually the red line is in the middle (big ring) or to the far right (small ring). I've tried applying a lot of force to the button but it seems completely jammed.

[image]

Lastly here is a picture of the front derailleur.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a way of knowing absolutely this is true, but it sounds like a severe case of the unnamed phenomenon where the shifter gets pushed into its (presumably) last click, and the system is set up such that this position pushes the front derailer to the absolute limit of what the limit screw and the stretchiness of the cable allow. The cable then statically has a very large amount of tension on it (much more than what the FD return spring provides, which is what the shifting mechanism is designed in mind for), and this makes shifting back take a lot of force, or in rare cases not work at all.

If this is what's going on, the main clue would be that cable has an inordinate amount of tension when you pluck it with your finger. The fix is to take a screwdriver and back out the front derailer high limit screw a couple full turns. Then you should be able to downshift as normal. After this you should ideally set the derailer back up again from square one, because if this can happen at all then something isn't quite right. If that's too much you can just reset the high limit back to the normal .5-1mm or so of chain clearance, but you might have to repeat the episode in the future, and this is one of the main contributors to STI levers failing early.

Comment: It is sometimes possible to release this by pressing both shift levers - the upshift lever releases enough tension for the ratchet to release. Not all levers are built to allow this, though. Failing that, IME it's usually better to release the attachment bolt on the derailleur, as that adjustment is easier to make, as well as more obvious and less dangerous if made incorrectly.

Comment: Hey Nathan, I tried unscrewing the high limit screw (was there anything i needed to do before this?) and alas the button/lever are still jammed up.

Comment: Ok I pushed the lever that shifts the gear up (pretty bad idea) and now the button which I usually press to shift the gear down is completely stuck, completely static (whereas before it could be pressed down a little bit until being jammed). Thanks for the help guys, I might go and try resetting the front derailleur from scratch or something of the sort cause right now I have no clue what's going on xD

Comment: I would suggest loosening the cable end at the derailer, to remove all tension off of it.  (Note that backing off the high limit does no good since the derailer is wedged against the big ring.)

Comment: I agree with Daniel, take the cable out as that is what is more than likely holding all the tension. Afterwards you should be able to get it to "break loose"

Comment: FWIW the reason I think it's usually best just to do the limit screw is it's the simplest and fastest thing by far to adjust back, and it's always worked fine for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

okay, maybe this has been checked already, but check that the inner in the shifter hasn't been pulled out of its seating and is now making everything unresponsive! I had the same (okay, sounds like...) issue with an Ultegra STI and some new Jagwire inners when I did some very lazy forceful shifting (you say you had this problem since lending the bike out? Yeah, could be this...). If it is this? Loosen everything off, then try to 'find' the cable end in the body of the shifter...tweezers?..., reseat it, then reset the FD from scratch.
And don't let anyone borrow your stuff... :)

Comment: Generally if that happens the cable will "relax" and the derailer will move towards the small ring.